# Django: ProgrammingError when dealing with ManyToMany database

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, many-to-many

Started using `ManyToMany` relationships in my postgresql database, but I end up with

> "Programming Error : relation "sequences_sequence_access" does not exist"

can someone please explain to me my fault?

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Sequence(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    seq = models.TextField()
    access = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views

```
x = Sequence(name=mInput[0:mIndex])
x.seq = alnContent
x.save()
x.access.add(User.objects.get(username=mUsername)) #Problems start here
x.save()
```

Note: I did syncdb (but after doing it incorrectly once, and that field is still there and can't remove it)

Comment: Programming error means that you don't have that table in database. You might require migration

Comment: migration? sorry I don't get how to do that? isn't data migration moving databases from one system to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use migration here. You can use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)(for django<=1.6). BTW from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/):

> Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your
>   models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database
>   schema. They’re designed to be mostly automatic, but you’ll need to
>   know when to make migrations, when to run them, and the common
>   problems you might run into.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sync the database in order to reflect any changes you made to your models after the last sync.

Just run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

manage.py is your project directory.

Comment: Have you another models besides Sequence?